# How can I solve ?Error: CocoaPods's specs repository is too out-of-date to satisfy dependencies. To update the CocoaPods specs, run: pod repo update

Tags: flutter, dart

Hello after upgrading flutter I get an issues about pod and I can not run my project.I tried several ways for solving but unable to solve.I will share both terminal and pod file with you.Help Please

[image: it is podfile]

```
faridahmadov@Farids-MacBook-Air flutter_parisa % flutter run
```

Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone 14 in debug mode...
Running pod install...                                             505ms
CocoaPods' output:
↳
Preparing

```
Analyzing dependencies

Inspecting targets to integrate
  Using `ARCHS` setting to build architectures of target `Pods-Runner`: (``)

Finding Podfile changes
  A firebase_messaging
  - Flutter
  - audioplayers_darwin
  - cloud_firestore
  - firebase_auth
  - firebase_core
  - firebase_storage
  - path_provider_foundation
  - sqflite

Fetching external sources
-> Fetching podspec for `Flutter` from `Flutter`
-> Fetching podspec for `audioplayers_darwin` from `.symlinks/plugins/audioplayers_darwin/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `cloud_firestore` from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`
cloud_firestore: Using Firebase SDK version '10.7.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_auth` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`
firebase_auth: Using Firebase SDK version '10.7.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_core` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_core/ios`
firebase_core: Using Firebase SDK version '10.7.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_messaging` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_messaging/ios`
firebase_messaging: Using Firebase SDK version '10.7.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `firebase_storage` from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_storage/ios`
firebase_storage: Using Firebase SDK version '10.7.0' defined in 'firebase_core'
-> Fetching podspec for `path_provider_foundation` from `.symlinks/plugins/path_provider_foundation/ios`
-> Fetching podspec for `sqflite` from `.symlinks/plugins/sqflite/ios`

Resolving dependencies of `Podfile`
  CDN: trunk Relative path: CocoaPods-version.yml exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_f_4_e.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/f/4/e/FMDB/2.7.5/FMDB.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_0_3_5.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/10.8.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_6_1_e.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/6/1/e/nanopb/2.30909.0/nanopb.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/10.7.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: all_pods_versions_4_2_c.txt exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/4/2/c/FlutterMacOS/3.0.0/FlutterMacOS.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo
  update
  CDN: trunk Relative path: Specs/0/3/5/Firebase/10.7.0/Firebase.podspec.json exists! Returning local because checking is only performed in repo update
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Auth":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    Firebase/Auth (= 10.3.0)

  In Podfile:
    firebase_auth (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_auth/ios`) was resolved to 4.4.0, which depends on
      Firebase/Auth (= 10.7.0)


You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * changed the constraints of dependency `Firebase/Auth` inside your development pod `firebase_auth`.
   You should run `pod update Firebase/Auth` to apply changes you've made.

/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:317:in `raise_error_unless_state'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:299:in `block in unwind_for_conflict'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:297:in `tap'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:297:in `unwind_for_conflict'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:257:in `process_topmost_state'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolution.rb:182:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/molinillo-0.8.0/lib/molinillo/resolver.rb:43:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/resolver.rb:94:in `resolve'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1082:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:1080:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/installer/analyzer.rb:125:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:422:in `analyze'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:244:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:243:in `resolve_dependencies'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/installer.rb:162:in `install!'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/command/install.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Error output from CocoaPods:
↳

```
[!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `11.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this
target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
```

Error: CocoaPods's specs repository is too out-of-date to satisfy dependencies.
To update the CocoaPods specs, run:
pod repo update

Error running pod install
Error launching application on iPhone 14.
faridahmadov@Farids-MacBook-Air flutter_parisa %

- History restored

faridahmadov@Farids-MacBook-Air flutter_parisa % pod repo update
Updating spec repo `trunk`

――― MARKDOWN TEMPLATE ―――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

#### Command

```
/usr/local/bin/pod repo update
```

#### Report

- What did you do?
- What did you expect to happen?
- What happened instead?

#### Stack

```
   CocoaPods : 1.12.0
        Ruby : ruby 2.6.10p210 (2022-04-12 revision 67958) [universal.arm64e-darwin22]
    RubyGems : 3.0.3.1
        Host : macOS 13.2.1 (22D68)
       Xcode : 14.2 (14C18)
         Git : git version 2.37.1 (Apple Git-137.1)
Ruby lib dir : /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib
Repositories : trunk - CDN - https://cdn.cocoapods.org/
```

#### Plugins

```
cocoapods-clean       : 0.0.1
cocoapods-deintegrate : 1.0.5
cocoapods-plugins     : 1.0.0
cocoapods-search      : 1.0.1
cocoapods-trunk       : 1.6.0
cocoapods-try         : 1.2.0
```

#### Error

```
LoadError - dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle, 0x0009): tried: '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle' (no such file), '/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'x86_64', need 'arm64')) - /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi_c.bundle
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi.rb:5:in `rescue in <top (required)>'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ffi-1.15.5/lib/ffi.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/ethon-0.16.0/lib/ethon.rb:3:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/typhoeus-1.4.0/lib/typhoeus.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.6/usr/lib/ruby/2.6.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:440:in `download_typhoeus_impl_async'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:372:in `download_and_save_with_retries_async'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:365:in `download_file_async'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:338:in `download_file'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:78:in `deprecated_local_podspecs'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:60:in `preheat_existing_files'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-core-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods-core/cdn_source.rb:257:in `update'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:144:in `block (3 levels) in update'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/user_interface.rb:64:in `section'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:143:in `block (2 levels) in update'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:142:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:142:in `block in update'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:140:in `open'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/sources_manager.rb:140:in `update'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/command/repo/update.rb:23:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/claide-1.1.0/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/cocoapods-1.12.0/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

――― TEMPLATE END ――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――――

[!] Oh no, an error occurred.

Search for existing GitHub issues similar to yours:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/search?q=dlopen%28%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.15.5%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle%2C+0x0009%29%3A+tried%3A+%27%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.15.5%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle%27+%28mach-o+file%2C+but+is+an+incompatible+architecture+%28have+%27x86_64%27%2C+need+%27arm64%27%29%29%2C+%27%2FSystem%2FVolumes%2FPreboot%2FCryptexes%2FOS%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.15.5%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle%27+%28no+such+file%29%2C+%27%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.15.5%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle%27+%28mach-o+file%2C+but+is+an+incompatible+architecture+%28have+%27x86_64%27%2C+need+%27arm64%27%29%29+-+%2FLibrary%2FRuby%2FGems%2F2.6.0%2Fgems%2Fffi-1.15.5%2Flib%2Fffi_c.bundle&type=Issues

If none exists, create a ticket, with the template displayed above, on:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/new

Be sure to first read the contributing guide for details on how to properly submit a ticket:
https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Don't forget to anonymize any private data!

Looking for related issues on cocoapods/cocoapods...
Searching for inspections failed: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass
faridahmadov@Farids-MacBook-Air flutter_parisa %

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same issue with flutter

Deleted `Podfile.lock` under `ios` folder then run the project again.

It will be generated automatically

Answer (score 2):

Most of the times the answer is already in the error logs.

```
CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Auth":
...
You should run `pod update Firebase/Auth` to apply changes you've made.
```

Can you try that?

That happens to me regularly too, and when I run the command they suggest it always fixes the error.

After that you can try to run `pod install` and `pod update`

Answer (score 1):

Try running pod install --repo-update.

Comment: unfortunately It does not help

Answer (score 1):

Try "pod update Firebase/CoreOnly"

Comment: unfortunately it does not help.